# How do I get the Spotify Client ID and Client Secret without a Redirect URI for my Python Code?

Tags: python-3.x, spotify

I am trying to get the Spotify API working on Python, I know I need the Client ID and Client Secret but there might have been an update because I am not able to find a relevant tutorial.

I have watched a bunch of older tutorials where they are creating apps on the Spotify dashboard with just the name and description but I am not able to do so since it's asking for a Redirect URI on the Web API app creation screen. How do I skip this part? I am assuming I have to choose something other than Web API but I am not finding a relevant choice for Python.
[Choices provided on the Spotify Dashbaord](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnZ7Q.png)

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer:
I'm a newbie both in `python` & [Spotify API](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/tutorials/code-flow)*

> I have watched a bunch of older tutorials (...) it's asking for a Redirect URI on the Web API app creation screen. How do I skip this part?

To interact with Spotify API, you have [4 ways ("flows")](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/tutorials/code-flow) :

[image]

**CLIENT CREDENTIALS FLOW** :

The way (flow) that interests you is **Client credentials flow**, since it doesn't require a `redirect URI`, to interact with `Spotify API`.

From the ["Getting started" of Spotify's doc](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/tutorials/getting-started) :

- 1/ get an **access_token**

```
curl -X POST "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token" \
     -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
     -d "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&client_secret=YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET"
```

It returns you something like this :

```
{
  "access_token": "BQDBKJ5eo5jxbtpWjVOj7ryS84khybFpP_lTqzV7uV-T_m0cTfwvdn5BnBSKPxKgEb11",
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "expires_in": 3600
}
```

- 2/ **interact** with `Spotify API` *(eg. retrieve an artist metadatas)* :

```
curl "https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/4Z8W4fKeB5YxbusRsdQVPb" \
     -H "Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN_YOU_RETRIEVE_ABOVE"
```

**Disadvantage of this flow** :

You have a limited access to `Spotify API`, for example **you WILL NOT BE ABLE TO retrieve your albums**.

I couldn't tell from your post, but I imagine you want to be able to retrieve the user's **playlists** or **albums**.

From [Spotify doc](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/tutorials/client-credentials-flow) :

> Since this flow does not include authorization, **only endpoints that do not access user information can be accessed**.

So, you have to choose another "flow", to get some **authorization** from `Spotify API` (eg. retrieve your albums). And this is where the `redirect URI` is **relevant**.

**AUTHORIZATION CODE FLOW** :

> The authorization code flow is suitable **for long-running applications** (e.g. web and mobile apps) where the **user grants permission only once**. ([Spotify's doc](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/tutorials/code-flow))

I don't need a flow more suitable for mobile app (Authorization code PKCE), and [Spotify doesn't recommend the last one](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/tutorials/implicit-flow) (Implicit grant).

**MY IMPLEMENTATION WITH `python` & web framework [Flask](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flask_(web_framework))**:

*source code available [here](https://github.com/souriya777/spotify-connect-python)*

In `app.py` file I set:

- the `CLIENT_ID` & `CLIENT_SECRET`
- define 3 routes: `home`, `authorize`, `tokens`

```
### app.py
# I skip import etc...

CLIENT_ID = "YOUR_CLIENT_ID"
CLIENT_SECRET = "YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET"

# home
@app.route('/')
def home():
  return render_template('home.html')

# authorize
@app.route('/authorize')
def authorize():
  # user-library-read is the "scope authorization" to retrieve infos like ALBUMS
  # redirect_uri is encoded, but correspond to http://localhost:5000/tokens
  AUTHORIZE_URL = "https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=" + CLIENT_ID + "&scope=user-library-read&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A5000%2Ftokens%2F"
  return redirect(AUTHORIZE_URL)

# tokens
@app.route('/tokens/')
def tokens():
  authorizationCode = request.args.get('code')
  response = requests.post(
      url="https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token",
      data={
        'code': str(authorizationCode),
        'redirect_uri': "http://localhost:5000/tokens/",
        'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
        'client_id': CLIENT_ID,
        'client_secret': CLIENT_SECRET,
      }
  )

  jsonResponse = json.loads(response.content)

  for key in jsonResponse:
    if (key == 'access_token') :
      session['access_token'] = jsonResponse[key]
    elif(key == 'refresh_token') :
      session['refresh_token'] = jsonResponse[key]

  return render_template('tokens.html', access_token=session['access_token'], refresh_token=session['refresh_token'])

# my-albums
@app.route('/albums')
def myAlbums():
  response = requests.get(
      url="https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/albums?limit=50",
      headers={
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + session['access_token']
      },
  )

  jsonResponse = json.loads(response.content)
  
  return render_template('albums.html', albums=jsonResponse)
```

The `templates` `home.html`, `tokens.html` & `albums.html` are basic HTML, so I don't copy/paste them.

Test yourself, it would normally works !

**MY APP SETTINGS IN SPOTIFY'S DASHBOARD** :
[image: spotify app settings]

**THE HOME SCREEN, WITH "authorize" link**
[image: authorize]

**THE TOKENS SCREEN & a link to load my albums :**
[image: tokens]

**MY ALBUM AS `JSON`**:
[image: my albums]